# F sharp parameterized types - cartesian product

Tags: types, f#

Scott Wlaschin has a great tutorial on [parser combinators](https://vimeo.com/171704565).

In it is this code:

```
type Result<'a> =
    | Success of 'a
    | Failure of string

type Parser<'a>  = Parser of (string -> Result<'a * string>)
```

I understand that the Result type is paramaterized by 'a, and that objects constructed with `Parser` contain a function from `string` to `Result<'a * string>`.

I don't understand the `<'a * string>`. I know it's the cartesian product, and that `Result` can be either a `Success of 'a` or a `Failure of string`, but the type of `Result` is `Result<'a>` not `Result<'a * string>`.

Clearly I am missing something, and I'd be grateful for some help!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not the same `'a`. There is one `'a` in the definition of `Result` and a totally different, unrelated `'a` in the definition of `Parser`.

For the purposes of further explanation, I'm going to rename one of them, otherwise it's just going to be verbal spaghetti:

```
type Result<'a> =
    | Success of 'a
    | Failure of string

type Parser<'b>  = Parser of (string -> Result<'b * string>)
```

So here, inside the definition of `Parser`, we use `Result`, and give it `'b * string` as parameter. Therefore, inside the definition of `Result`, `'a = 'b * string`.

Which in turn means that there are two possible values:

1. `Success of ('b * string)`
2. `Failure of string`

The meaning of this is that a parser can either fail (returning an error as a `string`) or succeed, in which case it returns the resulting parsed value `'b` plus the "remainder" (aka "unconsumed part") of the input text.

---

From your comments it seems like you may be getting tripped up on the fact that `'a * string` seems to mirror `Result` cases `Success of 'a` and `Failure of string`.

This seeming symmetry is a pure coincidence. The `Parser` type just needed that to be `'a * string` for reasons completely unrelated to how the `Result` type itself is structured.

For further illustration, here are some other equally valid types:

```
type T = Result<int>
type U = Result<bool list>
type V<'a> = Result<int * 'a * string>
type W = Result<Result<float>>
type F<'q> = 'q -> Result<obj>
type G = Result<string> -> int
type H<'a, 'b, 'c> = Result<'a> -> Result<'b> -> Result<'c>
```

Comment: That helps me ask my question in a clear(er) way:
When I see `('b * string)`, I expect every object of type Result will be an element of the Cartesian product with both a `b` and a `string`. But that's only true  for Success (when, as you say, `'a = 'b * string`). `Failure of string` doesn't have an instance of `'a` inside it - how is that consistent with the parametisation of Result as <'a>?
Thanks

Comment: `Result<'a>` is not the same as `'a`. It contains values different than those of `'a`. Similarly, `Result<'b * string>` is not the same as `'b * string`. It contains values different than those of `'b * string`

Comment: OK - Yes, I see that. So why is the parameter written as `'b * string`. Why is `string` there at all? If there were a third option `|NotSure of int` would the type then be `'b * string * int`?
Again, thanks for your patience

Comment: I made an edit to the answer in an attempt to clear your confusion. Please check it out.

Comment: Yes - you have correctly identified my point of confusion - the symmetry b/n the structure of Result and the return type of the parser. I am one sentence away from enlightenment!

"The Parser type just needed that to be 'a * string for reasons completely unrelated to how the Result type itself is structured."

Why does the parser type need to be `'b * string`? - and wouldn't the type of Parser be dictated by the structure of Result.

Comment: I did explain in my answer why the parser needs that to be the result. In the successful case it needs to return both the parsed value and the remainder of the input text.

Comment: Yep - got it. Thanks again for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [the blog post](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/understanding-parser-combinators/#implementation-3-returning-a-successfailure) might explain a little better.

It may be clearer if we replace `'a` with a real example. Say you wanted to parse a `char`, you'd create a `Parser<char>`. That parser would contain a function `string -> Result<char * string>`. In the context of `Result<'a>`, `'a` is `char * string` - it's *not* the same `'a` as `Parser<'a>`.

The result of that function would, then, either be `Success of (char * string)` or `Failure of string`.

In the `Success` case, `char * string` is a tuple - the first item is the `char` parsed, the second item is the remaining `string`. The idea would be that if parsing `"ABC"` the result might be `Success ('A', "BC")`.

In the `Failure` case, `string` is some error message - e.g. `Failure ("Expecting 'A'. Got 'Z'")`.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't looked at the blog. I find his style (written and oral) quite clear and engaging.